# On decompositions of integers as a linear combination of $(1, 2, 3,\ldots)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, elementary-proofs

Edited: Given integer $N\geq 0$, let $$I(N):=\Bigl\{(n_k)_{k\geq 1}\in {\mathbb N}^\infty \,:\, n_k\geq 0, \sum_{k\geq 1}kn_k = N \Bigr\}$$ be the set of all decompositions of $N$ as a linear combination of $(1, 2, 3,\ldots)$ with nonnegative integer coefficients. Then $$\sum_{(n_k)\in I(N)}\prod_{k\geq 1} \frac{1}{k^{n_k} n_k!} = 1.$$
Is there a simple (non Fourier analytic) proof of this identity?

Comment: The exponent of the exponential doesn't depend on the $n_k$; is that intentional?

Comment: Looks like cycle-index formula.

Comment: If the formula is written correctly, then we can notice that the product splits into two factors, one of which is $\prod_{k\geq 1}e^{-\lambda^k/k}=e^{-\sum_{k\geq 1}\lambda^k/k}=e^{\log(1-\lambda)}=1-\lambda$. This way we basically reduce the problem to the case $\lambda=0$.

Comment: Yes, it is intentional and Wojowu's observation is correct. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you multiply both sides by $N!$, then you are just enumerating permutations of $1,2,\dots,N$ according to their cycle type.